# top-answerers / top-askers documentation bug: number of results returned incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, api, api-v2.2, documentation

The [top-answerers-on-tags](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/top-answerers-on-tags) and [top-askers-on-tags](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/top-askers-on-tags) documentation claim:

> Returns the **top 30 answerers** active in a single tag, of either all-time or the last 30 days.

and

> Returns the **top 30 askers** active in a single tag, of either all-time or the last 30 days.

Both return 20 results. This is consistent with the per-tag [top users pages](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/topusers), which also show just 20 users, for the past 30 days.

This is simple documentation bug; it should simply read **top 20** instead.

Comment: Yeah, I also verified the same in both the periods **month** and **all_time** . it returns 20 records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this'll be corrected after the next API build.